# Prove a sequence converges to f(A).

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, continuity

[image]

[image]

I would like to know if this is an accurate proof

Comment: Since $a_n$ converges to $A,$ there is an $N$ such taht for $n \geq N,$ $|a_n-A| < \delta.$ Does this help?

Comment: @jflipp please see my edit, is this correct?

Comment: You can state it more explicitly. Instead of "So by the definition ...", I would say "So for every $\epsilon > 0,$ we have found an $N$ such that for $n \geq N$ we have $|f(a_n) - f(A)| < \epsilon.$ Thus, $f(a_n)$ converges to $f(A).$

Comment: @jflipp But otherwise it is all I need?

Comment: Yes, that's all you need.

Answer (score 1):

Find a $N$ for each $\alpha$ :
$$\text{f continuous in L}\in\mathbb{R}\iff\forall\epsilon>0, \exists \alpha > 0 \text{ s.t } \forall x \in \left[L-\alpha, L+\alpha\right], \left|f(x) - f(L)\right| < \epsilon.$$
$$\lim\left(a_n\right)_{n\geq0} = L\iff\forall\alpha>0, \exists N > 0 \text{ s.t } \forall n > N, \left|a_n - L\right| < \alpha.$$
and $\left|a_n-L\right|<\alpha \iff L-\alpha \leq a_n \leq L+\alpha \iff a_n \in \left[L-\alpha, L+\alpha\right]$

Answer (score 0):

I'll give a small hint, because you seem like you've almost got a full proof: Is a convergent sequence necessarily Cauchy? How is the answer to this question useful?

Comment: Please see my edit, thank you.